How do I set the start page for the browser version of the app in the Avalonia UI cross-platform app?
I'm writing a cross-platform application and I've done the page navigation logic. It works for phones and computers and for Windows and Android emulator everything works, but for browser version it doesn't. It just defaults to "Powered by Avalonia".
I don't know how to fix it
here is the code for page navigation
using Avalonia.Controls;

namespace QuizApplication.Services
{
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        void Register<TViewModel, TView>() where TViewModel : class where TView : Control;
        void NavigateTo<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : class;
    }
}

using Avalonia.Controls;
using QuizApplication.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace QuizApplication.Services;

public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly Window? _mainWindow;
    private readonly MainView? _mainView;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _registrations;

    public NavigationService(Window mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
        _registrations = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    }

    public NavigationService(MainView mainView)
    {
        _mainView = mainView;
        _registrations = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    }

    public void Register<TViewModel, TView>() where TViewModel : class where TView : Control
    {
        _registrations[typeof(TViewModel)] = typeof(TView);
    }

    public void NavigateTo<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : class
    {
        if (_registrations.TryGetValue(typeof(TViewModel), out var viewType))
        {
            var view = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType)!;
            view.DataContext = viewModel;

            if (_mainWindow != null)
            {
                _mainWindow.Content = view;
            }
            else if (_mainView != null)
            {
                _mainView.Content = view;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No valid main view available for navigation");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"View model {typeof(TViewModel)} is not registered");
        }
    }
}

using QuizApplication.Services;
using QuizApplication.ViewModels.MainPagesViewModels;
using QuizApplication.Views.MainPagesViews;

namespace QuizApplication.ApplicationSetup
{
    public static class PagesRegistration
    {
        public static void RegisterPagesMapping(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            navigationService.Register<MainPageViewModel, MainPageView>();
        }
    }
}

using QuizApplication.Services;
using QuizApplication.ViewModels.MainPagesViewModels;

namespace QuizApplication.ApplicationSetup
{
    public static class StartupNavigation
    {
        public static void NavigateToInitialPage(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            navigationService.NavigateTo(new MainPageViewModel());
        }
    }
}

here's the file App.axaml.cs.
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.ApplicationLifetimes;
using Avalonia.Data.Core.Plugins;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;
using QuizApplication.ApplicationSetup;
using QuizApplication.Services;
using QuizApplication.ViewModels;
using QuizApplication.Views;

namespace QuizApplication
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }

        public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
        {
            INavigationService navigationService = null!;

            if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
            {
                // Line below is needed to remove Avalonia data validation.
                // Without this line you will get duplicate validations from both Avalonia and CT
                BindingPlugins.DataValidators.RemoveAt(0);
                desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
                {
                    DataContext = new MainViewModel()
                };

                navigationService = new NavigationService(desktop.MainWindow);
            }
            else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
            {
                var mainView = new MainView
                {
                    DataContext = new MainViewModel()
                };

                singleViewPlatform.MainView = mainView;
                navigationService = new NavigationService(mainView);
            }

            PagesRegistration.RegisterPagesMapping(navigationService);

            StartupNavigation.NavigateToInitialPage(navigationService);

            base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
        }
    }
}

I don't know if these files are necessary, but I'm going to add
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>QuizApplication.Browser</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="out">
        <div class="avalonia-splash">
            <h2>
                Powered by
                <a href="https://www.avaloniaui.net/" target="_blank">
                    <svg width="266" height="52" viewBox="0 0 266 52" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M55.8592 47.3941C54.9035 47.3941 54.1184 47.1723 53.504 46.7285C52.9237 46.2848 52.5483 45.6875 52.3776 44.9365C52.2411 44.1856 52.3947 43.3493 52.8384 42.4277L65.9456 13.7045C66.4917 12.544 67.1403 11.7077 67.8912 11.1957C68.6421 10.6496 69.5125 10.3765 70.5024 10.3765C71.4923 10.3765 72.3627 10.6496 73.1136 11.1957C73.8645 11.7077 74.496 12.544 75.008 13.7045L88.2176 42.4277C88.6613 43.3493 88.8149 44.2027 88.6784 44.9877C88.576 45.7387 88.2347 46.336 87.6544 46.7797C87.0741 47.1893 86.3232 47.3941 85.4016 47.3941C84.2411 47.3941 83.3365 47.1211 82.688 46.5749C82.0736 46.0288 81.5275 45.1755 81.0496 44.0149L78.9279 39.0997H62.0415L59.9552 44.0149C59.4432 45.2096 58.8971 46.08 58.3168 46.6261C57.7707 47.1381 56.9515 47.3941 55.8592 47.3941ZM70.4 19.2853L64.6844 32.9045H76.2627L70.5024 19.2853H70.4Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M101.869 47.3941C100.879 47.3941 100.009 47.1381 99.258 46.6261C98.5071 46.08 97.9096 45.2779 97.4659 44.2197L89.7348 26.4021C89.3593 25.5147 89.2228 24.6955 89.3252 23.9445C89.4276 23.1595 89.786 22.5451 90.4004 22.1013C91.0489 21.6235 91.9364 21.3845 93.0628 21.3845C93.9844 21.3845 94.7353 21.6064 95.3156 22.0501C95.8959 22.4597 96.4079 23.2619 96.8516 24.4565L102.018 37.95L107.552 24.4053C108.03 23.2448 108.559 22.4597 109.14 22.0501C109.72 21.6064 110.522 21.3845 111.546 21.3845C112.433 21.3845 113.133 21.6235 113.645 22.1013C114.191 22.5451 114.516 23.1424 114.618 23.8933C114.755 24.6443 114.618 25.4635 114.208 26.3509L106.324 44.2197C105.88 45.312 105.283 46.1141 104.532 46.6261C103.815 47.1381 102.927 47.3941 101.869 47.3941Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M126.569 47.4965C124.726 47.4965 123.07 47.1381 121.602 46.4213C120.135 45.7045 118.991 44.7317 118.172 43.5029C117.353 42.2741 116.943 40.8917 116.943 39.3557C116.943 37.5125 117.421 36.0619 118.377 35.0037C119.333 33.9115 120.886 33.1435 123.036 32.6997C125.186 32.2219 128.037 31.9829 131.586 31.9829H133.43V35.9765H131.638C129.897 35.9765 128.48 36.0789 127.388 36.2837C126.33 36.4544 125.562 36.7616 125.084 37.2053C124.64 37.6491 124.418 38.2635 124.418 39.0485C124.418 40.0043 124.743 40.7893 125.391 41.4037C126.074 42.0181 127.047 42.3253 128.31 42.3253C129.299 42.3253 130.17 42.1035 130.921 41.6597C131.706 41.1819 132.32 40.5504 132.764 39.7653C133.208 38.9461 133.43 38.0245 133.43 37.0005V31.1125C133.43 29.6107 133.088 28.5525 132.406 27.9381C131.723 27.2896 130.562 26.9653 128.924 26.9653C128.002 26.9653 126.995 27.0848 125.903 27.3237C124.845 27.5285 123.667 27.8869 122.37 28.3989C121.619 28.7403 120.954 28.8256 120.374 28.6549C119.793 28.4501 119.35 28.1088 119.042 27.6309C118.735 27.1189 118.582 26.5728 118.582 25.9925C118.582 25.3781 118.752 24.7979 119.094 24.2517C119.435 23.6715 119.998 23.2448 120.783 22.9717C122.387 22.3232 123.889 21.8795 125.289 21.6405C126.722 21.4016 128.037 21.2821 129.231 21.2821C131.859 21.2821 134.01 21.6747 135.682 22.4597C137.389 23.2107 138.669 24.3883 139.522 25.9925C140.376 27.5627 140.802 29.5936 140.802 32.0853V43.4517C140.802 44.7147 140.495 45.6875 139.881 46.3701C139.266 47.0528 138.379 47.3941 137.218 47.3941C136.058 47.3941 135.153 47.0528 134.505 46.3701C133.89 45.6875 133.583 44.7147 133.583 43.4517L133.594 43.15C133.594 43.15 133.293 44.032 132.61 44.8853C131.962 45.7045 131.126 46.3531 130.102 46.8309C129.078 47.2747 127.9 47.4965 126.569 47.4965Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M155.632 47.4965C152.594 47.4965 150.324 46.6603 148.822 44.9877C147.321 43.2811 146.57 40.7552 146.57 37.4101V14.3189C146.57 13.0219 146.894 12.0491 147.542 11.4005C148.225 10.7179 149.198 10.3765 150.461 10.3765C151.69 10.3765 152.628 10.7179 153.277 11.4005C153.959 12.0491 154.301 13.0219 154.301 14.3189V37.1029C154.301 38.5024 154.591 39.5435 155.171 40.2261C155.786 40.8747 156.588 41.1989 157.578 41.1989C157.851 41.1989 158.107 41.1819 158.346 41.1477C158.585 41.1136 158.841 41.0965 159.114 41.0965C159.66 41.0283 160.035 41.1989 160.24 41.6085C160.479 41.984 160.598 42.752 160.598 43.9125C160.598 44.9365 160.394 45.7216 159.984 46.2677C159.574 46.7797 158.943 47.1211 158.09 47.2917C157.748 47.3259 157.356 47.36 156.912 47.3941C156.468 47.4624 156.042 47.4965 155.632 47.4965Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M175.453 47.4965C172.756 47.4965 170.401 46.9675 168.387 45.9093C166.407 44.8512 164.871 43.3323 163.779 41.3525C162.687 39.3728 162.141 37.0347 162.141 34.3381C162.141 32.3243 162.448 30.5152 163.062 28.9109C163.677 27.3067 164.564 25.9413 165.725 24.8149C166.919 23.6544 168.336 22.784 169.974 22.2037C171.613 21.5893 173.439 21.2821 175.453 21.2821C178.149 21.2821 180.487 21.8112 182.467 22.8693C184.481 23.9275 186.034 25.4293 187.126 27.3749C188.253 29.3205 188.816 31.6416 188.816 34.3381C188.816 36.3861 188.492 38.2123 187.843 39.8165C187.229 41.4208 186.341 42.8032 185.181 43.9637C184.02 45.1243 182.604 46.0117 180.931 46.6261C179.293 47.2064 177.467 47.4965 175.453 47.4965ZM175.453 41.7109C176.579 41.7109 177.552 41.4379 178.371 40.8917C179.19 40.3456 179.839 39.5435 180.317 38.4853C180.795 37.3931 181.034 36.0107 181.034 34.3381C181.034 31.8464 180.522 30.0203 179.498 28.8597C178.474 27.6651 177.125 27.0677 175.453 27.0677C174.361 27.0677 173.388 27.3237 172.534 27.8357C171.715 28.3477 171.067 29.1499 170.589 30.2421C170.145 31.3003 169.923 32.6656 169.923 34.3381C169.923 36.8299 170.435 38.6901 171.459 39.9189C172.483 41.1136 173.814 41.7109 175.453 41.7109Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M197.411 47.3941C196.148 47.3941 195.175 47.0528 194.492 46.3701C193.844 45.6875 193.52 44.7147 193.52 43.4517V25.2757C193.52 24.0128 193.844 23.0571 194.492 22.4085C195.175 21.7259 196.114 21.3845 197.308 21.3845C198.537 21.3845 199.476 21.7259 200.124 22.4085C200.773 23.0571 201.112 24.1871 201.112 25.45C201.141 25.3955 202.48 23.552 204.016 22.6645C205.586 21.7429 207.361 21.2821 209.34 21.2821C211.354 21.2821 213.01 21.6747 214.307 22.4597C215.604 23.2107 216.577 24.3712 217.225 25.9413C217.874 27.4773 218.198 29.44 218.198 31.8293V43.4517C218.198 44.7147 217.857 45.6875 217.174 46.3701C216.525 47.0528 215.57 47.3941 214.307 47.3941C213.078 47.3941 212.122 47.0528 211.44 46.3701C210.791 45.6875 210.467 44.7147 210.467 43.4517V32.1877C210.467 30.4469 210.143 29.2011 209.494 28.4501C208.88 27.6651 207.924 27.2725 206.627 27.2725C204.988 27.2725 203.674 27.7845 202.684 28.8085C201.729 29.8325 201.251 31.1979 201.251 32.9045V43.4517C201.251 46.08 199.971 47.3941 197.411 47.3941Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M227.861 47.3429C226.598 47.3429 225.625 46.9845 224.942 46.2677C224.294 45.5168 223.97 44.4757 223.97 43.1445V25.6341C223.97 24.2688 224.294 23.2277 224.942 22.5109C225.625 21.76 226.598 21.3845 227.861 21.3845C229.09 21.3845 230.028 21.76 230.677 22.5109C231.359 23.2277 231.701 24.2688 231.701 25.6341V43.1445C231.701 44.4757 231.377 45.5168 230.728 46.2677C230.079 46.9845 229.124 47.3429 227.861 47.3429ZM227.861 17.1861C226.427 17.1861 225.318 16.8619 224.533 16.2133C223.782 15.5307 223.406 14.5749 223.406 13.3461C223.406 12.0832 223.782 11.1275 224.533 10.4789C225.318 9.79629 226.427 9.45496 227.861 9.45496C229.294 9.45496 230.387 9.79629 231.138 10.4789C231.889 11.1275 232.264 12.0832 232.264 13.3461C232.264 14.5749 231.889 15.5307 231.138 16.2133C230.387 16.8619 229.294 17.1861 227.861 17.1861Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M246.169 47.4965C244.326 47.4965 242.67 47.1381 241.202 46.4213C239.735 45.7045 238.591 44.7317 237.772 43.5029C236.953 42.2741 236.543 40.8917 236.543 39.3557C236.543 37.5125 237.021 36.0619 237.977 35.0037C238.933 33.9115 240.486 33.1435 242.636 32.6997C244.786 32.2219 247.637 31.9829 251.186 31.9829H253.03V35.9765H251.238C249.497 35.9765 248.08 36.0789 246.988 36.2837C245.93 36.4544 245.162 36.7616 244.684 37.2053C244.24 37.6491 244.018 38.2635 244.018 39.0485C244.018 40.0043 244.343 40.7893 244.991 41.4037C245.674 42.0181 246.647 42.3253 247.91 42.3253C248.899 42.3253 249.77 42.1035 250.521 41.6597C251.306 41.1819 251.92 40.5504 252.364 39.7653C252.808 38.9461 253.03 38.0245 253.03 37.0005V31.1125C253.03 29.6107 252.688 28.5525 252.006 27.9381C251.323 27.2896 250.162 26.9653 248.524 26.9653C247.602 26.9653 246.595 27.0848 245.503 27.3237C244.445 27.5285 243.267 27.8869 241.97 28.3989C241.219 28.7403 240.554 28.8256 239.974 28.6549C239.393 28.4501 238.95 28.1088 238.642 27.6309C238.335 27.1189 238.182 26.5728 238.182 25.9925C238.182 25.3781 238.352 24.7979 238.694 24.2517C239.035 23.6715 239.598 23.2448 240.383 22.9717C241.987 22.3232 243.489 21.8795 244.889 21.6405C246.322 21.4016 247.637 21.2821 248.831 21.2821C251.459 21.2821 253.61 21.6747 255.282 22.4597C256.989 23.2107 258.269 24.3883 259.122 25.9925C259.976 27.5627 260.402 29.5936 260.402 32.0853V43.4517C260.402 44.7147 260.095 45.6875 259.481 46.3701C258.866 47.0528 257.979 47.3941 256.818 47.3941C255.658 47.3941 254.753 47.0528 254.105 46.3701C253.49 45.6875 253.183 44.7147 253.183 43.4517V43.1789C253.183 43.3144 252.893 44.032 252.21 44.8853C251.562 45.7045 250.726 46.3531 249.702 46.8309C248.678 47.2747 247.5 47.4965 246.169 47.4965Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path d="M22.3444 20.9916C18.7895 20.9916 15.9077 24.0073 15.9077 27.7274C15.9077 31.4475 18.7895 34.4632 22.3444 34.4632C25.8993 34.4632 28.7811 31.4475 28.7811 27.7274C28.7811 24.0073 25.8993 20.9916 22.3444 20.9916Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M37.6937 49.0667H21.9271C10.8346 48.8653 1.90173 39.3893 1.90173 27.7333C1.90173 15.9513 11.0289 6.40002 22.2878 6.40002C33.3638 6.40002 42.3768 15.6435 42.6667 27.161L42.6314 44.4824C42.338 47.0679 40.2434 49.0667 37.6937 49.0667ZM9.22617 24.667C10.5612 18.3725 15.9275 13.6656 22.3444 13.6656C29.7657 13.6656 35.7818 19.9613 35.7818 27.7274C35.7818 27.7857 35.7825 27.8488 35.7831 27.9136C35.7846 28.0483 35.7861 28.1901 35.7818 28.3103V41.6939H28.7907V40.0685C26.877 41.1655 24.6803 41.7892 22.3444 41.7892C15.9275 41.7892 10.5612 37.0823 9.22617 30.7878C10.5043 30.4129 11.4416 29.1847 11.4416 27.7274C11.4416 26.2701 10.5043 25.0419 9.22617 24.667ZM8.33937 29.9683C9.52696 29.9683 10.4897 28.9609 10.4897 27.7181C10.4897 26.4753 9.52696 25.4678 8.33937 25.4678C7.15178 25.4678 6.18904 26.4753 6.18904 27.7181C6.18904 28.9609 7.15178 29.9683 8.33937 29.9683Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                    </svg>   
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type='module' src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

app.css
/* HTML styles for the splash screen */
.avalonia-splash {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Light theme styles */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    .avalonia-splash {
        background: white;
    }

    .avalonia-splash h2 {
        color: #1b2a4e;
    }

    .avalonia-splash a {
        color: #0D6EFD;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .avalonia-splash {
        background: #1b2a4e;
    }

    .avalonia-splash h2 {
        color: white;
    }

    .avalonia-splash a {
        color: white;
    }
}

.avalonia-splash h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.avalonia-splash a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    display: block;   
}

.avalonia-splash.splash-close {
    transition: opacity 200ms, display 200ms;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

I have the main.js and Program.cs files for the browser by default too
I realize this is a very long question, but please help.
ChatGPT didn't give a good answer
